# test contents of javascript in cucumber

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cucumber

I have an application, Rails, tested with Cucumber. This application has a Google Map and I want a Cucumber-step to test whether or not that map has some "Pins" (Markers). 
As far as I know, the pins cannot be found in the DOM, so I thought to simply test, whether or not the page calls `map.addMarker()` with certain parameters.

```
Then /^I should see the top 50 campings on the map$/ do
  Camping.geocoded.top(50).each do |camping|
    page.should have_content /map\.addMarker\(#{camping.latitude}, #{camping.longitude}, "#{camping.name}"\)/
  end
end
```

The page has a script tag at the bottom that gets filled with a `content_for`, the source has:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(map.addMarker(51.7780246, 5.97571, "Bij Ons"))
</script>
</body>
```

`map.addMarker` is some custom JavaScript, which adds a marker to the map.

I am not (really) interested in testing whether my custom JavaScript and the Google maps API actually turns that call into a visible pin (although that would be neat); for now simply testing if that JavaScript method gets called will do.

How can I test whether `page` contains certain JavaScript? The code in the `Then` step above, only tests for actual content and omits the content in the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to not use `have_content`, but a more versatile selector, like `have_xpath`:

```
page.should have_xpath "//script[contains(.,'map.addMarker(#{camping.latitude}, #{camping.longitude}, \"#{camping.name}\")')]"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me I needed to add the visible false `page.should have_xpath "//script[contains(., 'blah')]", visible: false`